# Realtime query-based data rules example

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console, firebase-security

**Situation**

I have a simple model with collections of items.
Each item has an 'owner' field with the auth.uid of the creator as its value.

[image]

My model is to put listeners (child_added & al) on the collections, however I want users to get only what is relevant to them. The recommended way to do that is using query-based rules, [cf. documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data).

I have written rules that I believe to be a copy-paste of those given in the documentation, but the simulator fails on all read simulations, pointing at the query-based rule.

[image]

I can't believe this is a bug, but I cannot find where I messed up either.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, this is frustrating me beyond words.

**EDITED** I also checked that the simulator's behaviour is coherent with what I observe when listeners are set on the collection.

```
db = firebase.database()
db.ref('list').on('child_added', snap => {
   console.log(snap.val()
})
```

The above code with query-based data rules gives nothing, while the following code, with no .read restriction, results in item1 object being displayed in the console

```
db = firebase.database()
var ref = db.ref('list').orderByChild('owner').equalTo("B3jj2of5EAWOUZ8xH0ZJ01X4Lhq1")
ref.on('child_added', snap => {
   console.log(snap.val()
})
```

Comment: I don't think the rules simulator can be used to test query based security rules. Can you show a screenshot of what you tried in the simulator and how it responds?

Comment: Hi Frank @FrankvanPuffelen, I edited the question to simplify both data & rules, and show the result of the simulator. Of course I copy-pasted the user ID from the value of list/item1/owner.
And I just tried with a simpler userId ("user1") to make sure it is not a problem of bad user ID copy-pasting.

Comment: Can you test this in code instead of the firebase rules simulator? If this is simply something that can't be done in the simulator @FrankvanPuffelen knows where you can file a feature request for it.

Comment: @AndréKool orderByChild() does work in JS code, I specifically target the database rules behaviour. 

To put .on('child_added') listeners, I need to have .read  permissions on the list, not individual items. And giving .read at the list level implies that no filtering is possible.

Comment: @Titou I don't really understand your comment. If this (query + query based rules) works in your code it is just a matter of not being able to test query based rules in the simulator.

Comment: @AndréKool  I reproduced the problem with JS code and I am confident it is a problem with the rules not with the simulator. 

What works is  db.root.child('list').orderByChild('owner').equalTo(auth.uid).on('child_added', <callback>) 


What doesn't work is
db.root.child('list').on('child_added', <callback>) 
with query-based data rules

Comment: @AndréKool.  I asked the question to understand whether these query-based rules work or not.

What I want to achieve is a bit more complicated, as I would like to filter through group membership testing - and not just ownership.
But that will be for another question.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to test this to your question?

Comment: @AndréKool  I only use the .on('child_added', <callback>). The result is sent to an Elm subscription. I will take some time to set up a separate minimal JS testing code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173151/discussion-between-titou-and-andre-kool).

Comment: That behavior in your last edit sounds correct to me. The second to last snippet is not allowed, since it's trying to read all of `/list`. The last snippet *is* allowed, since you're filtering by UID, which is what your rules check for.

Comment: Thank @FrankvanPuffelen for taking the time. 

I understand that data rules not authorizing the full list to be read will block any attempt to do so ; that means that the restriction of the rules must be matched in the actual query attempt.  In turn, those data rules are really security safeguards only, in case the code is misconducting, and cannot be used to develop simpler querying code.